# Prototype function different id elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, string, prototypejs, getelementbyid

I'm making this prototype script to work:

```
function removing () {
*var ids = $$('.class').collect(function(el) { return el.id; });* //array of ids, not used by now
var data = $$('.class').pluck('innerHTML');
var wanted_count = 10;
var output = cutHtmlString(data, wanted_count);
$$('.class').invoke('replace', output + '...');
}
```

on this markup:

```
<div class="class" id="id1">content 1</div>
<div class="class" id="id2>content 2</div>
<div class="class" id="id3>content 3</div>
```

cutHtmlString is a function that cut html strings keeping tags and I want to apply it to every different div content. I create 'data' variable (by innerHTML) from general $$(.class) and then I execute cutting by a words count (var wanted_count) into 'output' var.
At the end I replace the original element (by $$.class again) with its new cut content.
All works great except for one issue: using only $$(class) makes **only the first element content to be considered and replaced** to every others.
I need to identify elements by ids too, I guess..thus I added the commented function upon (collect) but I don't know how to join my target..
By now I only got to this results:

> this is the content of firts 'class'
>   div...*(cut)*
> this is the content of firts 'class' div...
>   
>  this is the content of firts 'class' div...

while I want to get:

> this is the content of first 'class'
>   div...
>       this is the content of second 'class' div...
>       this is the content of third 'class' div...

thanks guys and an appreciation to this great community whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are mixing working on a collection of elements with working on a single element. It's been a while since I've been in Prototype, but have you tried to work on very individually so output is scoped to the element you are replacing:

```
function removing () {
  var data, output, wanted_count = 10;

  $$('.class').each(function(element){
    output = cutHtmlString(element.innerHTML, wanted_count);
    element.replace(output + '...');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke` only woks if your padding the same variables to each element. You need to use `each`.
Also I think you want to use `update` and not `replace`.

try this.

```
function removing() {
  $$('.class').each(function(el){
    var output = cutHtmlString(el.innerHTML, 10);
    el.update(output + '...');
  });
}
```